# Ruby Module has access to class methods it was required in?

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance, methods, module

I don't quite understand how this works:

```
module Perimeter
  def perimeter
    sides.inject(0) { |sum, side| sum + side }
  end
end

class Rectangle
  include Perimeter

  def initialize(length, breadth)
    @length = length
    @breadth = breadth
  end

  def sides
    [@length, @breadth, @length, @breadth]
  end
end

class Square
  include Perimeter

  def initialize(side)
    @side = side
  end

  def sides
    [@side, @side, @side, @side]
  end
end
```

When you call `Rectangle.new(2, 3).perimeter` it returns 10 as expected.

In this case, the module gets the arguments by calling the `sides` method from the class.
How can a module have access to that method? Is it because of `include` keyword?

Comment: You're thinking about this incorrectly. The *module* does not have access to `sides`, the instance of `Square` simply has access to its own methods and properties, including the methods "mixed into" the class by including a module.

Comment: `include` is actually a method called on the class object. So `include Perimeter` is equivalent to `self.include(Perimeter)`. Also note that `sides.inject(0) { |sum, side| sum + side }` is equivalent to `self.sides.inject(0) { |sum, side| sum + side }`. `self` can and is usually omitted if you are able to do so. But be sure to research `self` when you have time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can a module have access to that method?

That's *exactly* what modules do. Basically, you can define a bunch of methods in a module, then include it, and the end result is as if those methods were in your class directly.

If you want more technical, including a module injects it into your class' ancestors chain.

```
Rectangle.ancestors # => [Rectangle, Perimeter, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

You might be familiar with `Enumerable` module. It contains many useful methods, like `reduce`, `map`, `count` and others. They're all implemented with method `each` and that's the one method that Enumerable module does not implement. It's the missing piece. Now, if you have a class (some kind of collection, perhaps. Genealogy tree or something) and it implements `each`, you can include `Enumerable` in that class and voilà, now you can `map` your collection. Same thing in your case with `perimeter` and `sides`.

Comment: So it really is the include keyword. Thanks!

Comment: "the end result is as if those methods were in your class directly." – No. `include` makes the module the superclass of the class it is mixed into. That is *not* the same as if those methods were defined in the class.

Comment: @MarkEdmuund: "So it really is the include keyword" – There is no `include` keyword. `include` is a method defined in the class `Module`.